# Guardar variable de sesión PHP dudas con if

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy trabajando en un ejercicio que consiste en guardar una variable de sesión si una combinación de numero es valida, debo retornar al cliente un mensaje de confirmación si se ha guardado o no.
La validación la hago solo con PHP, debo controlar que sean 4 dígitos y que no hayan letras, mi problema es con el if ya que no sé como plantearlo y si ingreso alguna letra nunca me da el mensaje de error:

PHP:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $combi = $_GET['combinacion'];//aca recibo los parametros enviados desde JS
  
  $afirmativo = "VALIDADO - SESION GUARDADA";
  $negativo = "NO VALIDADO -Hay letras o hay mas de 4 valores";

  if(strlen($combi) ==4){   //$combi tiene 4 caracteres, entonces entra.
    if(preg_match("/^([0-9])*$/",$combi) ==1) {   // NUNCA ENTRA AUNQUE HAYA LETRAS
        //En esta instancia debería guardar la sesión y enviar mensaje
        if (!isset ($_SESSION['numeros'])){
            $_SESSION['numeros'] = $combi;
                echo '{"resp":"'.$afirmativo.'"}';
        }else{
            $combi =  $_SESSION['numeros'];   //SI YA EXISTE LA SESION NO LA REEMPLAZA
        }     
    }    
  }else{
      echo '{"resp":"'.$negativo.'"}';  //SON MAS DE 4 CARACTERES O HAY LETRA
  }
?>
```

Comment: Nunca te va mostrar el mensaje de error porque no le has puesto ninguna condicion, solo valdas si es numero y si no lo es, no hay ninguna condicion

Comment: Hola Juan, mi intención era que muestre $negativo, y la condicion creia haberla declarado en (preg_match("/^([0-9])*$/",$combi) ==1) si es true, no tiene letras, si es false envia mensaje de error, no se si me explico correctamente, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no le estas mandando ningun `else` al segundo `if`

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $combi = $_GET['combinacion'];//aca recibo los parametros enviados desde JS
  
  $afirmativo = "VALIDADO - SESION GUARDADA";
  $negativo = "NO VALIDADO -Hay letras o hay mas de 4 valores";

  if(strlen($combi) ==4){   //$combi tiene 4 caracteres, entonces entra.
    if(preg_match("/^([0-9])*$/",$combi) ==1) {   // NUNCA ENTRA AUNQUE HAYA LETRAS
        //Codigo   
    }    
  }else{
      echo '{"resp":"'.$negativo.'"}';  //SON MAS DE 4 CARACTERES O HAY LETRA
  }
?>
```

Vamos a ponernos por casos para que se entienda:

- Si `if(strlen($combi) == 4)` es correcto entonces se ejecuta el segundo `if`
- Si no es correcto, entonces se ejecuta el `echo`

Ahora el segundo if

- Si `preg_match("/^([0-9])*$/",$combi) == 1` es correcto entonces se ejecuta el `codigo`
- Si no es correcto, entonces no se ejecutara nada porque no hay ningun `else`

La solucion es simple, agregar el `else` al segundo `if`

```
if(strlen($combi) ==4){   //$combi tiene 4 caracteres, entonces entra.
    if(preg_match("/^([0-9])*$/",$combi) ==1) {   // NUNCA ENTRA AUNQUE HAYA LETRAS
        //Codigo   
    }else{
        echo '{"resp":"Hay almenos una letra"}';
    }
  }else{
      echo '{"resp":"Son mas de 4 caracteres"}';  //SON MAS DE 4 CARACTERES
  }
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias